# My android project does not show the right drawables

Tags: image, android-layout

I have layout files for small, medium , large screens. But I notice that my project does not show the right drawables. For instance:-
I have an xml file called main.xml which should display an image on the app.

my res folder is structured
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

layout
main.xml  --- image here shows drawable in drawable-mdpi

layout-large
main.xml  ---- image here show drawable in drawable-mdpi instead of drawable-hdpi

image in drawable-hdpi is much bigger so I expect it to show in layout-large (main.xml) but it not instead it showing the one in mdpi.

Is it resolution of the image cos they bear the same name. If it is the resolution that is the problem please wat are the image resolution of all the dpi drawables. I have read many post but I cant answer my question.

ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

I got does resources above from the android developer site. Please this 120dpi does it mean resolution for the images. I dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are calling those images using "dp" instead of "px". See this for reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: Thanks alot @Guilherme I have checked it. Well am still abit confused.   My first question is this. How do you convert dp to px. Most graphics edit software work in px or inches.  Secondly image size on a layout varies based the other text that are there. I dont think there is a stand size for images for each layout. I have tried alot but still dont know how.

Comment: Please are there demos that specially address this issues